# How to grab only search terms from URL, ignoring multiple delimiters

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I edit this code to handle multiple delimiters? Currently, it checks for either `%7` or `|relevance` and removes it. But it does not handle multiple delimiters such as in the 2 URL examples below.

`https://www.example.com/en-us/search?pq=marketing+agriculture%7Crelevance%7CbestSeller%3Atrue`

`https://www.example.com/en-us/search?pq=marketing+agriculture|Crelevance|CbestSeller%3Atrue`

**It should only grab the words:** marketing agriculture from the two URLs above.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

if (params.has('pq')) {
  const pq = params.get('pq').split('&7').pop().replace('|relevance', '');
  console.log(pq);
}
```

**Desired output**: To get only the search terms from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const regX = /(\w+[\+]?\w+)/gm;

if (params.has('pq')) {
  const pq = params.get('pq').match(regX);
  console.log(pq && pq[0]);
}
```

Comment: But this would only work if the user searches those two words, `marketing` and `agriculture` were just an example. It needs to work for any search terms.

Comment: I have edited the regex, see if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

```js
let a = "https://www.example.com/en-us/search?pq=marketing+agriculture%7Crelevance%7CbestSeller%3Atrue"

// Converts Params to Object
const parseParams = (querystring) => {
  // parse query string
  const params = new URLSearchParams(querystring);
  const obj = {};
  // iterate over all keys
  for (const key of params.keys()) {
    if (params.getAll(key).length > 1) {
      obj[key] = params.getAll(key);
    } else {
      obj[key] = params.get(key);
    }
  }
  return obj;
};

let aURL = new URL(a) // get the URL instance
let queryObj = parseParams(aURL.search) // grab and parse the parameter string (.search)
let search = queryObj.pq.split('|')[0] // grab the 'pq' prop (i.e that holds the search value.) and split it to get the actual search string
console.log(search)
```